# Ansible: manipulate vars and pass to templates

Tags: ansible

i have ansible playbook which push configuration file to server and reload the daemon.

---

```
- name: change configuration
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  template:
    src: templates/default.j2
    dest: /etc/varnish/default.vcl

- name: Change varnish demon 
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  shell: |
    sed -e '/ExecStart/ s/^#*/#/' -i /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service
    sed -i '10iExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -p feature=+esi_ignore_https -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m' /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service
    systemctl daemon-reload
  notify: Restart varnish
```

i call this role inside another role by including this

```
- include_role:
    name: varnish
  vars:
    CidrBlock: "{{ my_stack.ansible_facts.cloudformation[stack_name].stack_outputs.CidrBlock }}"
```

this var output something like 10.1.0.0/16, i pass this var to template and everything get deployed. but i want to pass var to the template without /16, that means i want 10.1.0.0 only to be pass to template. how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

solve this from cloud formation itself, manipulated output from cloud formation and gather that output and pass to ansible template cause i couldn't find a way to do this manipulation on ansible side.

```
 "CidrBlock2":{
     "Value":{
     "Fn::Join" : [ ".", [ "10", {"Ref": "ClassB"}, "0","0" ] ]
     }
  }
```